# Достать класс из другого файла, при этом сохранив модули

Tags: python, классы

У нас есть общая папка `common/classes` в которой мы храним классы, и допустим, хотим взять и запустить метод одного такого класса из другой папки `all_code/some_part`. В моём случае всё отлично импортируется, но единственная проблема, что в методе класса используется переменная (welcome_message) и 2 модуля (time, requests), которые импортированы и заданы в файле another_file.py

Хотелось бы не импортировать все эти модули в файле some_filename.py, так как в реальности их гораздо больше, чем 2. Так же дела обстоят с переменными. То есть задача импортировать класс из другого файла и чтобы этот класс видел все локальные и глобальные переменные из файла another_filename.py и при этом не прописывая имена вручную.

Структура проекта следующая:

```
common --
    classes --
        some_filename.py
all_code --
    some_part --
        another_file.py
run_it_all.py
```

И предположим, содержимое another_file.py:

```
from common.classes.some_filename import className
import time
import requests

welcome_message = "Method is going to start working!"
output = className.methodName('https://google.com')
print(output)
```

А содержимое файла some_filename.py:

```
class className:
   def methodName(self, url):
       print(welcome_message)
       return {'html' : requests.get(url), 'time' : time.time()}
```

run_it_all.py:

```
from all_code.some_part import *
```

В моём случае есть файл на 700 строк, из которого нужно одну функцию перенести в другую папку, чтобы иметь доступ к ней с любой точки проекта, но эта функция используется локальные переменные и модули. То есть я просто хочу импортировать код, но чтобы модули использовались в том месте, где я его имортирую.

Надеюсь на помощь, заранее спасибо!

Comment: У вас похоже проблема в архитектуре проекта. И вот этот print(welcome_message) он точно нужен как часть метода класса? Или это неудачный пример? Просто по логике - такая отдельная функция не нужна в методе класса.

Comment: Вообще суть в том, что мне нужно использовать модули, которые уже итак импортированы (чтобы в каждом файле не импортировать кучу модулей по несколько раз)

Comment: Вообще не понятно... Если модули уже импортированы, зачем их еще раз импортировать? Возможно у вас для именно ваших модулей не настроены `__init__.py` файлы?

Comment: Чтобы лучше понять вашу проблему, объясните зачем `нужно одну функцию перенести в другую папку, чтобы иметь доступ к ней с любой точки проекта`? Почему нельзя/плохо импортировать из того места, где она уже находится?

Comment: Если большой проект, посмотрите на тему "dependency injection / IoC" (в питоне я это пока не использовал).